# How can I identify what is causing this Apex error?

Tags: apex, batch, error, roll-up-summary, dlrs

```
Error Type: Batch Apex error
Error Date: 2016-11-04 03:10:08
Message: "First error: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 

003A000000uVn8nIAC; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, 

dlrs_ContactTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate

caused by: System.NoAccessException: Entity is not api accessible

Class...."
Context: npsp__RLLP_OppContactRollup_BATCH

Stack Trace:
 null
```

The above error started appearing this week, despite releasing no new Apex code recently.

What is the best way to debug and fix the error? We are running the latest versions of both Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries Tool and the Nonprofit Success Pack.

Comment: @AndrewFawcett - Just mentioning so you could see this

Comment: What object is being added/changed when you are seeing this error?

Comment: @Jagular The error is coming via email when the nightly batch rollups are running. I believe it's for the Contact object.

Comment: DLRS Issues page is place to post this: https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/issues

Comment: This error typically means the a) version you are running in is requesting an object or field not available to that version (note Winter17 just rolled out) or b) Apex compiler is confused between a variable/object name and some OOTB object/field name

Comment: Double check every API Name.

Comment: @AdrianLarson where should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your `Lookup Rollup Summary` tab and look at all records. For every record, you want to make sure that all of the following `API Names` are correct:

- `Parent Object`
- `Child Object`
- `Relationship Field`
- `Field to Aggregate`
- `Aggregate Result Field`
- (Optional) `Field to Order By`

You could try to run the following script in `Execute Anonymous` and see if it catches the problematic `NoAccessException`:

```
Map<String, SObjectType> sObjects = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
for (dlrs__LookupRollupSummary__c summary : [
    SELECT
        dlrs__ChildObject__c,
        dlrs__ParentObject__c,
        dlrs__FieldToOrderBy__c,
        dlrs__FieldToAggregate__c,
        dlrs__RelationshipField__c,
        dlrs__AggregateResultField__c
    FROM dlrs__LookupRollupSummary__c
]){
    try
    {
        SObjectType childType = sObjects.get(summary.dlrs__ChildObject__c);
        SObjectType parentType = sObjects.get(summary.dlrs__ParentObject__c);
        SObject dummyChild = childType.newSObject();
        SObject dummyParent = parentType.newSObject();
        dummyParent.get(summary.dlrs__AggregateResultField__c);
        dummyChild.get(summary.dlrs__RelationshipField__c);
        dummyChild.get(summary.dlrs__FieldToAggregate__c);
        if (summary.dlrs__FieldToOrderBy__c != null)
            dummyChild.get(summary.dlrs__FieldToOrderBy__c);
    }
    catch (NoAccessException n)
    {
        system.debug(summary);
        system.debug(n);
    }
    catch (Exception pokemon)
    {
        system.debug('Gotta catch em all! - ' + pokemon);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to hook this code up to a `Visualforce Page` and run it as each `Profile` to see who might not have access.